# IVT, Runge Kutta system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I'm really getting frustrated with this question. Could someone give me some help to get me started on both a and b?

Comment: Can you give the title of the textbook ?

Comment: It's from a Canadian University assignment manual. The full title is Athabascau Math 376 Ordinary Differential Equations Assignment Manual. The textbook it references is Nagle's Ordinary Differential Equations 7th edition.

Comment: Apply the fact (true by definition) that the second derivative is the derivative of the derivative.